# Drupal 8 filefield_sources is not working with IMCE module

Tags: drupal-8, imce-file-browser

I am trying to use filefield_sources module with IMCE module in drupal 8 so that I can browse files from the server. But the URL for the file browser is not opening. I have debugged a bit a found that the onclick function that is written in /filefield_sources/src/Plugin/FilefieldSource/imce.php line no.105 is not getting rendered in html. And clicking the URL does nothing.

[image]